# Blender Python: How to address a particular node when multiple nodes of same name are present?

Tags: python

I use this command for extracting the diffuse bsdfs:

`base_material = bpy.data.materials['base_material']`

`all_nodes = base_material.node_tree.nodes`

`bsdfs = all_nodes.get('Diffuse BSDF')`

Now, when I `print(bsdfs)`,
I get this:
`<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse("Diffuse BSDF") at 0x7fec5af57008>`
However, I have multiple Diffuse BSDFs in my node graph and printing bsdfs is returning only one such instance. I wanted to know how can I get a list of all these principled bsdfs
Blender version: 2.92.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no two nodes with the same name. If you have multiple Diffuse BSDFs. they will be named (by default) `Diffuse BSDF`, `Diffuse BSDF.001` etc.

Instead you can loop over all nodes and check their `.type`. Use the Python console to find out that `all_nodes['Diffuse BSDF'].type` is `'BSDF_DIFFUSE'`, so you would do

```py
bsdfs = [node for node in all_nodes if node.type == 'BSDF_DIFFUSE']
```